# Is Erdogan using Islam as a political tool to influence the masses or manipulate the government's foreign policy?

Tags: democracy, turkey, political-system, islamic-state, recep-tayyip-erdogan

He right now is living like a Emperor, yes the definition here is right. Better than Putin right now. It has been said that he bought his own officials, deputies, judges, advocates etc.

The country is in a democratic regime but still It drives me to think that this is all very skeptical and suspicious of what he is doing.

And, if my first statement is correct, he might also use Islam as a pretext to wage war against the nation's neighboring countries.

Comment: Welcome to Politics Stack Exchange. In order to promote a healthy environment for learning about politics and political processes we try to maintain neutrality. This question, however, is written in a way which seems to be primarily about bashing a specific politician. Further, it is unclear what the question is actually asking about. Can you clarify?